# The small key-search circuit for brute-force of Bernstein

Tags: aes, brute-force-attack

I'm trying to understand [Understanding brute force](https://cr.yp.to/snuffle/bruteforce-20050425.pdf) by Bernstein. I couldn't understand how the described machine can brute force the AES.

> The attacker builds a very small key-search circuit. The key-search circuit has
>   three inputs: a 12-byte string $\beta$, a 4-byte integer $n$, and a 16-byte string $s$. The key-search circuit has one output: a 16-byte string $Z(\beta, n, s)$ defined recursively by $Z(\beta, 0, s) = s$ and $Z(\beta, n + 1, s) = Z(\beta, n, H(s \oplus (\beta, n))$.

Comment: Have you tried the Oechslin paper on rainbow tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial part is not just the definition of $Z$, which is a random walk in possible keys.  It's also how you use it, on the next page:

1. Search for $Z(\beta, 2^{23}, r_j)$ among $Z(\beta, 0, H(k_i)),$ $Z(\beta, 1, H(k_i)),$ $Z(\beta, 2, H(k_i)),$ $\dots,$ $Z(\beta, 2^{23} - 1, H(k_i))$.
2. If you find that $Z(\beta, 2^{23}, r_j) = Z(\beta, \ell, H(k_i))$, then you have a candidate trail to follow!
3. In this case, start over computing $Z(\beta, 2^{23}, r_j)$, but only go $2^{23} - \ell - 1$ steps until the state $(\beta, \ell + 1, s)$ rather than all the way down to $(\beta, 0, s')$.
4. If $H(s \oplus (\beta, \ell)) = H(k_i)$, you've found a candidate for $k_i$, namely $s \oplus (\beta, \ell)$.

One way to look at it is as follows: The function $H$ (*e.g.*, $k \mapsto \operatorname{AES}_k(18238)$) represents a directed graph where each node $k$ has exactly one successor $H(k)$.  Imagine the graph as a network of rivers on a terrain.  They're not all connected, but they flow in only one direction.

1. You're teleported onto a node in the middle of a river, and you're trying to find the node just behind you, but you can't look there.
2. You shoot out a scattershot of cheap drones.  They will record the node where they landed, and then flow down the river exactly $2^{23}$ steps before stopping and embedding themselves in the river bed.
3. You go to sleep for the night.  In the morning, you trawl down the river looking for a drone.  If you find one after $\ell$ steps, you go to the point where it started and move forward by $2^{23} - \ell - 1$ steps, and see if the *next* one is the node you were sitting on at the beginning.

Of course, the drone you find could have come down a different tributary of the river, so you might have to retry with another drone.

This is the rough idea: the model breaks down because rivers are never cyclic, and the *advantage* comes either from (a) precomputing where the drones landed (as in precomputed rainbow tables) so that you can save effort by reusing them for many trawlings, or (b) simultaneously trawling *and* shooting out drones in parallel, and then searching for a collision by sorting the nodes where the drones landed together with the nodes you trawled through.

Comment: Afaik, rainbow tables may not cover all the search space. If so, does this circuit has the same problem?

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, it's not guaranteed to give an answer, but if you repeat the process with fresh values of $\beta$, the fraction of the search space that you cover tends to converge to all of it.